# if event type is equal to touchstart

Tags: jquery, touch, mouseevent

I can check if `mousedown` has been triggered like so:

```
$(something).on("mousemove touchmove", function(e) {
    if (e.buttons == 1){
        // mouse is down
    }
})
```

Very simple question, how can I check if `touchstart` has been triggered in the above? I tried:

```
if (e.type === 'touchstart'){
    // touchstart has been triggered
}
```

This did now work at all. Can someone please provide direction as to how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` statement checking the `e.type` property is the correct logic to use. Your condition fails though, because you hook to `mousemove` and `touchmove`, not `touchstart`.

You need to either include `touchstart` in the event list:

```
$(something).on("mousemove touchmove touchstart", fn);
```

*Or* check the `type` property for `touchmove`, if that was your intent:

```
if (e.type === 'touchmove'){
    // touchmove has been triggered
}
```

Comment: My intention was to check the touchstart because I wanted to know if a user was swiping in touch device. I just checked it on Windows phone and it works, thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad to help.